# Spotlight reveal animation from centre of page with CSS/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Does anyone know how I might make a circular 'reveal' effect, so that my DOM elements are revealed from the page centre with a circle getting bigger and bigger.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Could you provide more info, and maybe a scheme/drawing so we can understand what you want to achieve exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try "hiding" the content with a mask div that has transparent background and big `box-shadow` that covers the entire page. With `border-radius:100%` you can ensure that it is a circle:

```js
$('body').on("click", function() {
 $(this).toggleClass('reveal');
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 2em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background: hotpink;
  color: #FFF;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  color: yellow;
}

/* the mask */

#mask {
    position: fixed; top:50%; left: 0; right: 0; margin: auto;
    width:0px; height:0px; border-radius: 100%; z-index: 99;
    transform:translateY(-50%) scale(1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 60em #FFF; /* big shadow */
    transition:1s;
}

.reveal #mask {
  width:100vw; height:100vw;
  transform:translateY(-50%) scale(1.5);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mask"></div>

<h1>Masking</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam maiores, placeat. Est unde provident placeat deleniti, modi ea. Corporis iste dolorem ullam culpa. Asperiores illum harum, possimus cum ad doloribus.</p>
<p>Ab soluta quidem quibusdam ullam error sapiente officiis, dolorum unde dolore corporis maiores delectus voluptate assumenda veniam? Nostrum eius ad sequi, nemo eos porro libero, nam, magni, perspiciatis fuga soluta!</p>
<p>Blanditiis maxime unde perspiciatis repudiandae ipsum, in nihil possimus officiis? Minus, perferendis debitis doloribus sint repellendus accusamus recusandae pariatur quisquam asperiores temporibus optio in. Quia quas nihil fugiat omnis hic?</p>
<p>Error cum tenetur cupiditate dolore, possimus vitae. Optio fuga ipsam sit amet modi unde, officia quo, tempore obcaecati quis, nihil. Natus, ducimus deserunt, minus consequuntur accusamus minima mollitia voluptatum optio.</p>
<p>Quibusdam, dolor deserunt. Quia quo, deleniti saepe perspiciatis. Delectus dolorum labore quidem debitis excepturi facilis assumenda magni ex. Architecto illum tenetur, harum nulla consequatur debitis aut sint officiis praesentium similique.</p>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/7o3jcsbt/

The reveal animation works through a class transition, to see it in action, click anywhere in the page to "reveal" the content (jQuery toggle).

Note: This is a basic experimental demo I created and might need some testing before implementing in a production environment.

Comment: Fantastic!!! Thanks!